# Find The quotient of a number

Tags: algorithm, numbers

There is a giving number `N` , i have to find out the number of integer for which the `repetitive division` with N gives quotient one.

For Ex:

```
N=8
Numbers Are 2 as: 8/2=4/2=2/2=1
            5 as  8/5=1
            6 as  8/6=1 
            7 and 8
```

**My Aprroach:** 
All the numbers from `N/2+1` to `N` gives me quotient `1` so

```
Ans: N/2 + Check Numbers from (2, sqrt(N))
```

Time Complexity `O(sqrt(N))`

Is there any better ways to do this, since number can be upto `10^12` and there can many queries ?

Can it be `O(1)` or `O(40)` (because 2^40 exceeds 10^12)

Comment: Note: `N/2 + Check Numbers from (2, sqrt(N))` --> `(N + 1)/2 + Check Numbers from (2, sqrt(N))`  Example `N==3`.

Answer (score 0):

First off, your algorithm is not `O(sqrt(N))`, as you are ignoring the number of times you divide by each of the checked numbers. If the number being checked is `k`, the number of divisions before the result is obtained (by the method described above) is `O(log(k))`. Hence the complexity becomes `N/2 + (log(2) + log(3) + ... + log(sqrt(N)) = O(log(N) * sqrt(N))`.

Now that we have got that out of the way, the algorithm may be improved. Observe that, by repeated division and  you will get a `1` for a checked number `k` only when `k^t <= N < 2 * k^t` where `t=floor(log_k(N))`.

That is, when `k^t <= N < 2 * k^(t+1)`. Note the strict `<` on the right-side.

Now, to figure out `t`, you can use the Newton-Raphson method or the Taylor's series to get logarithms very quickly and a complexity measure is mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm#Computational_complexity). Let us call that `C(N)`. So the complexity will be `C(2) + C(3) + .... + C(sqrt(N))`. If you can ignore the cost of computing the `log`, you can get this to `O(sqrt(N))`.

For example, in the above case for N=8:

- `2^3 <= 8 < 2 * 2^3` : 1
- `floor(log_3(8)) = 1` and `8` does not satisfy `3^1 <= 8 < 2 * 3^1`: 0
- `floor(log_4(8)) = 1` and `8` does not satisfy `4^1 <= 8 < 2 * 4^1` : 0
- `4` extra coming in from numbers `5`, `6`, `7` and `8` as `8` `t=1` for these numbers.

Note that we did not need to check for `3` and `4`, but I have done so to illustrate the point. And you can verify that each of the numbers in `[N/2..N]` satisfies the above inequality and hence need to be added.

If you use this approach, we can eliminate the repeated divisions and get the complexity down to `O(sqrt(N))` if the complexity of computing logarithms can be assumed negligible.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like `O(1)` lookup per query, the hash table of naturals less than or equal `10^12` that are powers of other naturals will not be much larger than 2,000,000 elements; create it by iterating on the bases from 1 to 1,000,000, incrementing the value of seen keys; roots `1,000,000...10,001` need only be squared; roots `10,000...1,001` need only be cubed; after that, as has been mentioned, there can be at most 40 operations at the smallest root.

Each value in the table will represent the number of base/power configurations (e.g., `512 -> 2`, corresponding to `2^9` and `8^3`).

Answer (score 0):

A test harness to verify functionality and assess order of complexity.

Edit as needed - its wiki

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long nn = 0;

unsigned repeat_div(unsigned n, unsigned d) {
  for (;;) {
    nn++;
    unsigned q = n / d;
    if (q <= 1) return q;
    n = q;
  }
  return 0;
}

unsigned num_repeat_div2(unsigned n) {
  unsigned count = 0;
  for (unsigned d = 2; d <= n; d++) {
    count += repeat_div(n, d);
  }
  return count;
}

unsigned num_repeat_div2_NM(unsigned n) {
  unsigned count = 0;
  if (n > 1) {
    count += (n + 1) / 2;
    unsigned hi = (unsigned) sqrt(n);
    for (unsigned d = 2; d <= hi; d++) {
      count += repeat_div(n, d);
    }
  }
  return count;
}

unsigned num_repeat_div2_test(unsigned n) {
  // number of integers that repetitive division with n gives quotient one.
  unsigned count = 0;

  // increment nn per code' tightest loop
  ...

  return count;
}

///

unsigned (*method_rd[])(unsigned) = { num_repeat_div2, num_repeat_div2_NM,
    num_repeat_div2_test};
#define RD_N (sizeof method_rd/sizeof method_rd[0])

unsigned test_rd(unsigned n, unsigned long long *iteration) {
  unsigned count = 0;
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < RD_N; i++) {
    nn = 0;
    unsigned this_count =  method_rd[i](n);
    iteration[i] += nn;
    if (i > 0 && this_count != count) {
      printf("Oops %u %u %u\n", i, count, this_count);
      exit(-1);
    }
    count = this_count;
    // printf("rd[%u](%u)      = %u.  Iterations:%llu\n", i, n, cnt, nn);
  }

  return count;
}

void tests_rd(unsigned lo, unsigned hi) {
  unsigned long long total_iterations[RD_N] = {0};
  unsigned long long total_count = 0;
  for (unsigned n = lo; n <= hi; n++) {
    total_count += test_rd(n, total_iterations);
  }
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < RD_N; i++) {
    printf("Sum rd(%u,%u) --> %llu.  total Iterations %llu\n", lo, hi,
        total_count, total_iterations[i]);
  }
}

int main(void) {
  tests_rd(2, 10 * 1000);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's see since number can be upto `10^12` , what you can do is Create for number `2 to 10^6` , you can create and Array of `40` , so for each length check if the number can be expressed as `i^(len-1)+ y` where `i` is between 2 to 10^6 and len is between `1` to `40`.

So time complexity `O(40*Query)`